# Calculating probability of finding the particle using Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, superposition, quantum-tunneling

> An electron can be in one of two potential wells that are so close that it can ‘tunnel’ from one to the other. Its state vector can be written
>
> $|ψ\rangle = a|A\rangle + b|B\rangle$,
>
> where $|A\rangle$ is the state of being in the first well and $|B\rangle$  is the state of being in the second well and all kets are correctly normalised. What is the probability of finding the particle in the first well given that:
>
> (a) $ a = i/2; $
>
> (b) $b = e^{iπ} $;
>
> (c) $ b = 1/3 + i/\sqrt{2}?$

My thoughts:
since all kets are correctly normalised, so $aa^*+bb^*=1$, then the probability in the first well is calculating $|\langle A|a\rangle|^2$, can you us (a) to show me how to process it?? thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The probability of the particle to be found in the state $|A\rangle$ is $|\langle A |\psi\rangle |^2$.

In case you have never come across this expression, $\langle A |\psi\rangle $ is called the  *(probability) amplitude* of the state $|A\rangle$ and is basically telling you "how much" of that state there is in the total wavefunction $\psi$. Mathematically, it is an inner product.

The square of the probability amplitude gives you the actual probability of the particle to be in that particular state (or better, to have the eigenvalue associated with that eignemode, in this case $|A\rangle$).

So, here: $p(A) = |\langle A |\psi\rangle |^2 = |a|^2 = aa^* $

so for (a) $p(A) = (1/2)^2 = 1/4 $.

Then you can calculate $a$ knowing $b$ from the normalisation condition, as you have already explained. From $|a|^2 + |b|^2$ = 1 isolate $|a|^2$.

Comment: I think the question and the answer assume that $aa^* + bb^*=1$, which I think implies that $|A>$ and $|B>$ are orthogonal? Is this an ok assumption to make?

Comment: @tom Well, the OP defined $|A\rangle$ as the "state of being in the first well" and $|B\rangle$ as "the state of being in the second well" which - to my mind - implies that the two states are mutually exclusive (i.e. orthogonal).

Comment: @Geoffrey - yes that makes sense - I was just wondering about it. Maybe I should ask a separate question about it to take it further - thanks for your comment.

Comment: the second one I got 3, which is greater than 1, is that weird?

Comment: @Tom: sorry, I should probably have specified that - I just assumed they were orthogonal, since, as Geoffrey noticed, the two conditions are pretty much mutually exclusive.

Comment: @kengkeng: for (3), I get that $|b|^2 = \sqrt{ (1/3)^2 + (1/\sqrt{2})^2}$, so $ p(A) = |a|^2 = 1 -|b|^2 = 1 - \sqrt{1/9 + 1/2} \approx 0.2812... $

Comment: @kengkeng: sorry you meant the second one: $|b|^2 = 1$, as it is just a pure phase factor (or if you want, $e^{i\pi} = -1$) so, to ensure overall normalisation, $a$ needs to be 0.
The particle is in the second well, state $|B\rangle$.
Even from the formula you get $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ with  $|b|^2 = 1$ so you must have $p(A) = |a|^2 = 0$

Comment: oh, thanks, I might got it wrong on calculation. thank you guys!